# What is firebase_url in firebase android project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I had started firebase login with facebook and google plus.

I read following tutorial

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/samples/logindemo/MainActivity.java

```
  /* Create the Firebase ref that is used for all authentication with Firebase */
    mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(getResources().getString(R.string.firebase_url));
```

In above code what is "**firebase_url**". When I found from firebase website.

I want to check user already login with facebook or google account.

Or Is another way to check user already logged with firebase.

Kindly, Help me.

Comment: Try to read https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login

Comment: I read the entire document but no such method to find user exists. eg. Gmail user abc@gmail.com login with firebase. Second time login then log message user already exists.

Answer (score 0):

mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://your-app.firebaseio.com/"); is firebase reference by old Firebase.com.
Your Firebase example is constructed by old Firebase.com. You can upgrade your existing Firebase.com app to the new Firebase console and APIs.

https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android

or use, for authentication and to check if user already logged, new firebase example project by

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth